# Get back my funds after a mistaken self transaction on Cardano

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I accidentally made a self-transaction with my account and would like to know if I can get it back.
As you can see my account [here](https://cardanoscan.io/address/01fe424f32d70231494b27921b57a2485fe4e293ae76b7620216703f9c5d452ab59c3d40e339da2cc8fe5b57d280363eddd5152374adc4cd23), and this is [my self-transaction](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/c09ba4b187e823862b2a36df24166b1d3f9bdb64bfc504163592e23f998d7e0b) sent 2 weeks ago.

I'm using cardano-cli to run all my commands and was wondering if a script can give me my funds back. This was related to a pool already deregistered.

Thank you guys if you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibility for given description (I am assuming you meant second case below, but for completion will answer for both cases)

1. If you're referring to ~1671 ADA left after spending 500 ADA to register WINS pool, you made an outgoing transaction [here](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/cfc3e94b7b058c664211d319a89f38e482e92e5592cbd4899a01df38264f806c), which is when most of your funds on mentioned address were depleted. Since this isn't an internal transaction, you should check your target wallet where you sent funds.
   In case it helps remember, this target wallet was since delegated to `4ADA` pool
2. If instead you're referring to 500 ADA you spent as pool deposit in referred transaction, then your post is misleading. That was deposit you paid which could have only be returned IF your pool deregistration was fully complete (as long as your **stake account remained registered**), but seems your reward address is NOT registered, and thus - that account was left dangling and cannot get a refund, it would instead go back to reserves - unfortunately that'd mean you've lost that part due to the human error.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a self transaction, the only loss you should be seeing are the transaction fees.

> give me my funds back

Sorry, there is no way to reverse a transaction. You should already have you funds (minus the transaction fees).